# Double converted to String as label text displays wrong number

Tags: swift, string, label, double

When I use a double converted to a String as Labeltext, the text shows a wrong number.

let double = 17.2

let String = String(double)

label.text = String

Label text that is displayed:
17,20000000000000003

instead of

17,2

Why is that and is there a way to only display "17,2"?

Comment: Use `NumberFormatter` to convert a number to a string. Then you can format it as needed and it appears appropriate to the user based on their locale.

Answer (score -2):

of course you can print in any format you wish. This is for example format you proposed:

```
String(format: "%.1f", double)
```